# How to Repeat table in one report side

Tags: reporting, reportviewer, repeat

I have a simple report (1 Table with 2 small columns) 
the report works fine but now I'm trying to repeat the table on the same page but I can't find an example on how to do this.

I also crosses only one [question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c0cb3b55-f333-4810-ad58-50d3a190be89/repeat-table-in-report-reportviewer?forum=vsreportcontrols) about this problem, so maybe I miss something obviously on how to solve this.

Could somebody please enlight me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can 'play' with (a single) Tablix details to simulate table repetition.

For example you can create 3 rows of details like this:

- row 1: header
- row 2: value
- row 3: footer space

[image: table repetition]

To obtain a result like this:

[image: table repetition result]

You can also use a different layout, for example:

- row 1: label/value for column 1
- row 2: label/value for column 2
- row 3: footer space

If you have a very small table you can also set report columns to fill horizontal space.

[image: report columns]

This is the result (simulating table repetitions but you can also use a simple Tablix with standard header/details):

[image: report columns result]

This is the result if you use columns and a simple Tablix with standard header/details:

[image: report columns result 2]

Comment: thanks for your answer. so how would you do this horizontal? Because the space is on the right side.